# c++11 foreach syntax and custom iterator

Tags: c++, iterator, c++11

I am writing an iterator for a container which is being used in place of a STL container. Currently the STL container is being used in many places with the [c++11 foreach syntax](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) eg: `for(auto &x: C)`. We have needed to update the code to use a custom class that wraps the STL container:

```
template< typename Type>
class SomeSortedContainer{
    std::vector<typename Type> m_data; //we wish to iterate over this
    //container implementation code
};    
class SomeSortedContainerIterator{
    //iterator code
};
```

How do I get auto to use the correct iterator for the custom container so the code is able to be called in the following way?:

```
SomeSortedContainer C;
for(auto &x : C){
    //do something with x... 
}
```

In general what is required to ensure that auto uses the correct iterator for a class?

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio, you can hover over the variable's name to see its type. IIRC, it shows the actual type, not `auto`.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You have two choices:

- you provide member functions named `begin` and `end` that can be called like `C.begin()` and `C.end()`;
- otherwise, you provide free functions named `begin` and `end` that can be found using argument-dependent lookup, or in namespace `std`, and can be called like `begin(C)` and `end(C)`.

Comment: See Stroustrup's [C++11 FAQ](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html) for a detailed description of the ["Range-for" statement](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#for) (including member/function precedence).

Answer (score 53):

To be able to use range-based for, your class should provide `const_iterator begin() const` and `const_iterator end() const` members.  You can also overload the global `begin` function, but having a member function is better in my opinion.  `iterator begin()` and `const_iterator cbegin() const` are also recommended, but not required.  If you simply want to iterate over a single internal container, that's REALLY easy:

```
template< typename Type>
class SomeSortedContainer{

    std::vector<Type> m_data; //we wish to iterate over this
    //container implementation code
public:
    typedef typename std::vector<Type>::iterator iterator;
    typedef typename std::vector<Type>::const_iterator const_iterator;

    iterator begin() {return m_data.begin();}
    const_iterator begin() const {return m_data.begin();}
    const_iterator cbegin() const {return m_data.cbegin();}
    iterator end() {return m_data.end();}
    const_iterator end() const {return m_data.end();}
    const_iterator cend() const {return m_data.cend();}
};
```

If you want to iterate over anything custom though, you'll probably have to design your own iterators as classes inside your container.

```
class const_iterator : public std::iterator<random_access_iterator_tag, Type>{
    typename std::vector<Type>::iterator m_data;
    const_iterator(typename std::vector<Type>::iterator data) :m_data(data) {}
public:
    const_iterator() :m_data() {}
    const_iterator(const const_iterator& rhs) :m_data(rhs.m_data) {}
     //const iterator implementation code
};
```

For more details on writing an iterator class, see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8054856/845092).

Answer (score 8):

As others have stated, your container must implement `begin()` and `end()` functions (or have global or `std::` functions that take instances of your container as parameters).

Those functions must return the same type (usually `container::iterator`, but that is only a convention).  The returned type must implement `operator*`, `operator++`, and `operator!=`.

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge `SomeSortedContainer` just needs to provide `begin()` and `end()`. And these should return a standard compliant forward iterator, in your case `SomeSortedContainerIterator`, which would actually wrap a `std::vector<Type>::iterator`. With standard compliant I mean it has to provide the usual increment and dereferencing operators, but also all those `value_type`, `reference_type`, ... typedefs, which in turn are used by the foreach construct to determine the underlying type of the container elements. But you might just forward them from the `std::vector<Type>::iterator`.

Comment: If you lack the `begin` and `end` member functions then the foreach can also use the `begin` and `end` non-member functions.

Comment: @Mike Do you mean free functions taking the container as a single parameter? Nice, I didn't know that. Useful for extending existing container classes, I guess.