# Implementing custom iterators in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11

I am reading a book, and I started the **Templates** chapter. I have already read the chapter about iterators. For practicing, I am trying to implement a doubly-linked class using templates. Below is the header file of my class.

```
template<typename T>
class list
{
private:
    T* first_node;
    T* last_node;
    struct node_structure
    {
        T* previous;
        T* next;
        T content;
    };
public:
    list();
    void push_back( T& item );
    void push_front( T& item );
    void remove( size_t index );
    size_t size() const;
    T& get_node( size_t index );
    void clear();
    ~list();
};
```

I could have set two members:

```
T* begin();
T* end();
```

...to act like very basic iterators, but they are not iterators actually. So, I have a question:

How do I implement the custom iterator class to be used with all the arithmetic operations and to have `begin()`, `cbegin()`, `end()`, and `cend()`?

<sub>(I am aware that creating a list class will not be as efficient as `std::list`, but I am doing this just for sake of practicing.)</sub>

Comment: No, stackoverflow is no code review site but there is one that is http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: I know that. that's why I mentioned the second question as optional, because if somebody answers it, I will not be needed to post the same entry on **CodeReview**

Comment: It's two different questions so you definitely should. On a related note, you are not showing any implementation at all. So you might wanna implement it and then comeback to code review.

Comment: Ok then, but now I need advice about the iterators for my class, the first question in my post.

Comment: FYI, `T*` is in fact a perfectly valid iterator :)

Comment: not if you want to use operations like next element (it++). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8054273/how-to-implement-an-stl-style-iterator-and-avoid-common-pitfalls for an answer

Comment: Ah, my derp. `T*` could be a perfectly valid iterator for a `vector`-like container. But this is a linked list, and `T*` is indeed insufficient as an iterator. I stand corrected.

Comment: I'm a little confused here. Why do you have your node pointers as type `T`? Am I misreading this code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have a look at an implementation of `<iterator>`, you'll find something like `__normal_iterator`, which looks like:

```
template<typename I>
class iter
{
protected:
    I i;

    using tr = iterator_traits<I>;

public:
    using iterator_type     = I;
    using iterator_category = typename tr::iterator_category;
    using value_type        = typename tr::value_type;
    using difference_type   = typename tr::difference_type;
    using reference         = typename tr::reference;
    using pointer           = typename tr::pointer;

    iter() : i(I()) { }

    explicit iter(const I& i) : i(i) { }

    // Forward iterator requirements
    reference operator*() const { return *i; }

    pointer operator->() const { return i; }

    iter& operator++() { ++i; return *this; }

    iter operator++(int) { return iter(i++); }

    // Bidirectional iterator requirements
    iter& operator--() { --i; return *this; }

    iter operator--(int) { return iter(i--); }

    // Random access iterator requirements
    reference operator[](const difference_type& n) const { return i[n]; }

    iter& operator+=(const difference_type& n) { i += n; return *this; }

    iter operator+(const difference_type& n) const { return iter(i + n); }

    iter& operator-=(const difference_type& n) { i -= n; return *this; }

    iter operator-(const difference_type& n) const { return iter(i - n); }

    const I& base() const { return i; }
};
```

This is supposed to work on an ordinary pointer or iterator. All you have to do is use this as a template and adjust to what is needed by your custom container. If `T` is your `value_type`, then member functions normally return

- `begin()` -> `iter<T*>`
- `cbegin()` -> `iter<const T*>`
- `rbegin()` -> `std::reverse_iterator<iter<T*> >`
- `crbegin()` -> `std::reverse_iterator<iter<const T*> >`

However, since you have your `node_structure`, this is not entirely true and you need to elaborate a bit more.

Comment: of, it looks complex :)) I will see what I can do with it! Thank you

Comment: that's another reason to appreciate what we get with `std::list`!

Comment: read my last row in the post :D this is just for the sake of practicing

Comment: @Victor Plus, there are binary comparison operators `==`, `!=`, as well as `<`, `<=` etc. for random access, that I forgot to mention.

Comment: I will try to figure out by myself :)

Comment: @Victor For practice, you could skip the type traits and limit yourself to operators `*()`, `++()` (not `++(int)`), and `!=`. That's enough to see it in action in a `for` loop. Also forget `rbegin()` etc. Just make `begin()` and `end()`. Have fun!