# C++ when and how are std::iterator value_type, reference, pointer used?

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, reference, iterator

I'm writing a collection of containers and iterators for an environment where STL and Boost are off the table. I'm struggling somewhat with dealing with containers, such as a Vector, that can contain both value types and pointer types, when it comes to handling iterators and their return types - via a GetValue function, for example. It is further complicated by wanted to support const iterators. I have seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8054273/how-to-implement-an-stl-style-iterator-and-avoid-common-pitfalls) about the definition of a series of traits: value_type, reference, pointer. My question is how are these used in the context of creating iterators? Essentially, given that I want

```
Object & Vector<Object>::Iterator::GetValue()
Object * Vector<Object*>::Iterator::GetValue() 
const Object & Vector<Object>::ConstIterator::GetValue()
const Object * Vector<Object*>::ConstIterator::GetValue()
```

How do value_type, reference, pointer factor into this?

Comment: Did you try looking at what `std::vector` does? Hint: `std::vector<int *>::pointer` is `int **`.

Comment: @Potatoswatter Yes, it is clear that std::vector<int *>::pointer is **. My question relates to how these are used in the context of creating the correct signature for iterator's return type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The member types of iterators aren't used for very much. Fortunately, you don't need to bother defining them. The [`std::iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator) base class does it for you.

```
template< typename value_type >
struct my_vector_iterator
    : std::iterator< std::random_access_iterator_tag, value_type >
    …

template< typename value_type >
struct my_vector_const_iterator
    : std::iterator< std::random_access_iterator_tag, value_type const >
    …
```

Comment: As I mentioned, STL isn't available to me in these circumstances, but thank you for pointing out what's happening. In these cases is the 'value_type' just T or T*, if the container  contains pointers to type t?

Comment: @Steven Yes, it's that simple. If the container contains pointers, its implementation will involve pointers to pointers but never (ever) the pointed-to type directly.

Comment: So for std::vector<Object*> is the return type of the * operator on an iterator Object * & or Object * ?