# Making custom containers iterable

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

When defining my custom containers, it is more easy and very general (for me) making them iterable by just adding `size()` and `[]`. This is, having the following member methods:

```
unsigned int size() const { . . . }
T & operator[] (unsigned int pos) { . . . }
```

In order to benefit from the STL algorithms, I provide an adaptor
from *any* container class having the above methods to an iterator valid for the STL functions.
With it, I can write easily things like

```
MyContainer<int, 5> mc;
IteratorFromContainer<MyContainer<int,5>, int> iter (&mc);
int i=1; for (auto & e : iter) { e = i++; }
for (auto e=iter.begin(); e!=iter.end(); ++e) { cout << (*e) << endl; }  
int sum = std::accumulate(iter.begin(), iter.end(), 0);
int prod = std::accumulate(iter.begin(), iter.end(), 1, [](int a, int b) {return a*b;});
```

Surprisingly (to me) my adaptor (template) class works (the above sample code) equally well
with any of the following (1, 2, or 3):

```
template<typename Container, typename T>
// 1. 
class  IteratorFromContainer : public std::iterator<input_iterator_tag, T>  {
// 2. 
class  IteratorFromContainer : public std::iterator<output_iterator_tag, T>  {
// 3. 
class  IteratorFromContainer {
```

Why?. Should not the adaptor derive from `std::iterator` *always*?
What kind of iterator (what _tag) should I use, considering that the iterator is based in random access (size() and []) and has output and input capabilities: `RandomAccess, ContinguousIterator`?

Thanks

Comment: Very related but not sure if duplicate: [How to implement an STL-style iterator and avoid common pitfalls?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8054273/845092)

Comment: Note that in your examples, `IteratorFromContainer` does not appear to be trying to be an iterator at all.  It's an adaptor class, that _is itself iterable_.  The type of `iter.begin()` should be an iterator.  What type of iterator depends on the interface of that type, but I'd speculate it's easy enough to make it random access, which would use the `std::random_access_iterator_tag`.

Comment: Also, if you're crafty, you don't need people to pass `T` to `IteratorFromContainer`, you can deduce it from `decltype(mc[0])`.

Comment: `IteratorFromContainer` needs to implement the functions corresponding to the given iterator tag (like `std::output_iterator_tag`). The `iterator` base class only provides some typedefs.
It it doesn't, the iterator may still work when the code using it doesn't make use of functionality that it promises but doesn't have. Concepts in C++17 will probably allow the compiler produce errors in such cases.

Comment: @MooingDuck Thanks for your advice. Well, `IteratorFromContainer` is at the same time the iterable and the iterator: `IteratorFromContainer begin () const {
 return IteratorFromContainer(theContainer);
  }`

Comment: @cibercitizen1: That's... very weird and I recommend against it.  Better to have a give line adaptor class that doesn't do anything but create iterators.

Comment: @cibercitizen1: Like thus: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/548993ad8fcc075b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ uses a thing called duck-typing, which has awesome pros, and some really wierd cons.  One of those cons are, if you break the interface contract, it might not notice until much later, if ever.  When you use the for-loops, the compiler uses the iterator's copy constructor, `operator++()`, `operator==(...)` and `operator*()`, which you have, so it sometimes may work fine (I'm pretty sure GCC will point out the error in your options #2 & #3 though).  I don't know the exact requirements for `std::accumulate`, but most likely they're similar.  And so as long as you have those your code "works".

However, with options #2 and #3, you're breaking the "contract" about what it means to be an iterator.  As such, the compiler or library may receive an update, and your code may stop working.  The requirements for each iterator type depends on the type of iterator you're modeling, for more details see this page: [How to implement an STL-style iterator and avoid common pitfalls?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8054273/845092).  However, the minimum requirements are you must have these operations:

```
    iterator(const iterator&);
    ~iterator();
    iterator& operator=(const iterator&);
    iterator& operator++(); //prefix increment
    reference operator*() const;
```

and also `std::iterator_traits<IteratorFromContainer>` must have these typedefs:

```
typedef ???? difference_type; //almost always ptrdif_t
typedef ???? value_type; //almost always T
typedef ???? reference; //almost always T& or const T&
typedef ???? pointer; //almost always T* or const T*
typedef ???? iterator_category;  //usually std::forward_iterator_tag or similar
```

For simplicity, if you don't specialize `std::iterator_traits` yourself, it will check if your iterator has those typedefs, and if so, it will copy the ones from your iterator.  `std::iterator` has these typedefs, and so if you inherit from it, you automatically have the typedefs, and so `std::iterator_traits` will automatically have them, so you'll meet the contractual guarantees.  But inheriting from `std::iterator` is not necessary, you can add the typedefs yourself, or specialize `iterator_traits`.

Since you're working with `operator[]`, it makes sense for you to use `std::random_access_iterator_tag`, which has many more requirements than those listed above.  Again, see my other answer linked above for details on exactly what those members are.