# I have problems implementing the ++ increment operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am trying to provide a c++ interface for a c library I just finished, and I want it to be possible to write

```
for (DBITable table = db.tables() ; table != NULL ; table++)
```

where `db` is a class with a `tables()` method that returns the `DBITable` associated with it.

On compilation I get the following error with `clang++`

```
error: cannot increment value of type 'DBITable'
for (DBITable table = db.tables() ; table != NULL ; table++)
                                                    ~~~~~^
```

This is how i have implemented the `++` operator overload method

```c++
DBITable
DBITable::operator++()
{
    return next();
}
```

and it's declared in the `DBITable` class as

```c++
public:
    DBITable operator++();
```

the `table != NULL` part worked as I expected by doing this

```c++
bool operator!=(void *) 
{
    // evaluate and get the value
    return value;
}
```

Comment: The chart at the top of this page should be helpful: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_incdec

Comment: Why would you want such an operator for a table class? Operator overloading is supposed to make code easier to read. What does it mean to "increment" or "advance" a table? And will your code readers be familiar with this interpretation?

Comment: @ChristianHackl I will change the class name later. It is internally a linked list.

Comment: you may want to use pre-increment to avoid unnecessarily copying the iterator.

Comment: @iharob: That has the same problem. It is easy to picture a list iterator being advanced, but certainly not the list itself. As a matter of fact, `std::list` does not have a `++` operator, but its iterators do.

Comment: @ChristianHackl yes, immediately after fixing this problem, I am learning how to write an iterator. If you can give any help, a link to a good resource it will be appreciated.

Comment: @iharob: [How to implement an STL-style iterator and avoid common pitfalls?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8054273/845092)

Comment: @iharob: While learning how to write iterators is certainly a good thing to do, all I wanted to point out here is that you might use operator overloading for the wrong purpose.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`operator++()` is the prefix increment operator. Implement the postfix operator as `operator++(int)`.

The canonical implementations are have the prefix operator return a reference and the postfix operator return by value. Also, you would typically implement the postfix operator in terms of the prefix operator in the interests of least surprise and easy maintenance. Example:

```
struct T
{
 T& operator++()
 {
  this->increment();
  return *this;
 }

 T operator++(int)
 {
   T ret = *this;
   this->operator++();
   return ret;
 }
};
```

([Increment/decrement operators at cppreference.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_incdec))

Comment: Very very simple... :) And of course, there had to be a way to diferentiate the two. I just didn't find anything, the link posted by @chris explains it very well.

Comment: @iharob: You are not to blame for getting this wrong. In my opinion, it is the worst design decision in all of the vast C++ language.

Comment: @TonyK agree I would prefer something like `Class::++operator()` and `Class::operator++()` it would be more obvious.

Comment: @iharob: Or have the `operator++(int)` be compiler generated when you implement `operator++`.