# How can I implement various iterator categories in an elegant and efficient way?

Tags: c++, stl

I'm implementing STL containers, for example, vector. What confused me is the implementation of iterators.

If I want to implement all iterator categories: input_iterator, output_iterator, forward_iterator, bidirectional_iterator and random_access_iterator.

How do I manage their inheritance relationships?
I've read [How to implement an STL-style iterator and avoid common pitfalls?-Mooing Duck's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8054273/how-to-implement-an-stl-style-iterator-and-avoid-common-pitfalls)

This is his example symbolic:

```
iterator {
    iterator(const iterator&);
    ~iterator();
    iterator& operator=(const iterator&);
    iterator& operator++(); //prefix increment
    reference operator*() const;
    friend void swap(iterator& lhs, iterator& rhs); //C++11 I think
};
input_iterator : public virtual iterator {
    iterator operator++(int); //postfix increment
    value_type operator*() const;
    pointer operator->() const;
    friend bool operator==(const iterator&, const iterator&);
    friend bool operator!=(const iterator&, const iterator&); 
};
//once an input iterator has been dereferenced, it is 
//undefined to dereference one before that.
output_iterator : public virtual iterator {
    reference operator*() const;
    iterator operator++(int); //postfix increment
};
//dereferences may only be on the left side of an assignment
//once an input iterator has been dereferenced, it is 
//undefined to dereference one before that.
forward_iterator : input_iterator, output_iterator {
    forward_iterator();
};
//multiple passes allowed
bidirectional_iterator : forward_iterator {
    iterator& operator--(); //prefix increment
    iterator operator--(int); //postfix decrement
};

random_access_iterator : bidirectional_iterator {
    friend bool operator<(const iterator&, const iterator&);
    friend bool operator>(const iterator&, const iterator&);
    friend bool operator<=(const iterator&, const iterator&);
    friend bool operator>=(const iterator&, const iterator&);

    iterator& operator+=(size_type);
    friend iterator operator+(const iterator&, size_type);
    friend iterator operator+(size_type, const iterator&);
    iterator& operator-=(size_type);  
    friend iterator operator-(const iterator&, size_type);
    friend difference_type operator-(iterator, iterator);

    reference operator[](size_type) const;
};
```

But I found a problem:
If I have an instance `a` from class `random_access_iterator`, I use the code `random_access_iterator b = a + 1`. This will cause compile error. Because `a + 1`'s class is base `iterator`, not `random_access_iterator`.

So I don't think this is a reasonable solution.

Do I misunderstand it? Or please tell me an elegant and efficient way to implement it.

Thanks

Comment: Why not look at the `<vector>` source code?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: I've tried to read GCC's implementation, but it's a bit complex for me, I'm still trying to figure it out. But when I came across the implementation above, I'm impressed but not sure about its correctness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use CRTP (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern). 
Like this:

```
template <typename T, typename ItT>
struct iiterator_t {
    typedef T value_type;
    typedef T& reference;
    typedef T* pointer;

    typedef ItT iterator_type;

    virtual iterator_type& operator=(const iterator_type&) = 0;
    virtual iterator_type& operator++() = 0;
    virtual reference operator*() const = 0;
};

template <typename T, typename ItT>
struct iterator_impl_t :  virtual public iiterator_t<T, ItT>{
    typedef T value_type;
    typedef T& reference;
    typedef T* pointer;

    typedef ItT iterator_type;

    iterator_type& operator=(const iterator_type &rhs)
    {
        p = static_cast<const iterator_impl_t&>(rhs).p;
        return dynamic_cast<iterator_type&>(*this);
    }

    iterator_type& operator++()
    {
        ++p;
        return dynamic_cast<iterator_type&>(*this);
    }

    reference operator*() const
    {
        return *p;
    }

private:
    pointer p;
};

template <typename T, typename ItT>
struct iinput_iterator_t : public virtual iiterator_t<T, ItT> {
    typedef T value_type;
    typedef T& reference;
    typedef T* pointer;

    typedef ItT iterator_type;

    virtual iterator_type operator++(int) = 0;
};


template <typename T, typename ItT>
struct input_iterator_impl_t :
    public virtual iinput_iterator_t<T, ItT>,
    public virtual iterator_impl_t<T, ItT>
{
    typedef T value_type;
    typedef T& reference;
    typedef T* pointer;

    typedef ItT iterator_type;

    iterator_type operator++(int)
    {
        iterator_type result(dynamic_cast<const iterator_type &>(*this));
        ++dynamic_cast<iterator_impl_t<T, ItT> &>(*this);
        return result;
    }
};


template <typename T>
struct iterator :
    public virtual iterator_impl_t<T, iterator<T> >
{
};


template <typename T>
struct input_iterator :
    public virtual input_iterator_impl_t<T, input_iterator<T>>
{
};

int main(int , char** )
{
    iterator<int> i;
    iterator<int> i2 = ++i;
    input_iterator<int> inpi;
    input_iterator<int> inpi2 = inpi++;
    return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Iterator categories are nothing but empty structs that act as tags.

Once finished implementing the features of your iterator class, you add its information (like which category it belongs to) into a `std::iterator_traits` specialization.  Here's an example:

```
namespace std {

template <typename T>
struct iterator_traits<my_iota_iterator<T>> {
    using value_type = T;
    using difference_type = T;
    using pointer = T const*;
    using reference = T const&;
    using iterator_category = std::random_access_iterator_tag; // !!
} /*struct iterator_traits*/;

} /*namespace std*/;
```

You can also choose to place these type aliases directly in the iterator class itself.  Regardless, algorithms can now specialize upon the type of `iterator_category` and implement specific versions for specific categories.