# howto use find_if with non-container such as linked list?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, linked-list, iterator

I am trying to algorithm support for a static list of objects. I have tried to do this various ways but the only way I can get it to work is to write a traditional C for loop.

Example:

```
class ListNode
{
public:
    ListNode(int id);
    virtual ~ListNode() {}

    // Container support functions
    ListNode* operator++() {return m_nextNode;}
    static ListNode* findNode(int p_id);
    static ListNode* m_nodeList{nullptr};

private:
    int m_id;
    ListNode *m_nextNode;

protected:
    static void addNewNode(ListNode* p_node);

    friend ListNode* begin(void);
};

inline ListNode* begin(void) {return ListNode::m_nodeList;}
inline ListNode* end(void) {return nullptr;}

// Declare the list head
ListNode* ListNode::m_nodeList = nullptr;

// Constructor
ListNode::ListNode (int id): m_id{id}
{
    ListNode::addNewNode(this);
}

// Add node to front of list
void ListNode::addNewNode(ListNode* p_node)
{
    p_node->m_nextService = m_nodeList;
    m_nodeList = p_node;
}

//
// The following are all the find implementation attempts
//

ListNode* ListNode::failedFind1(int id) {
   return std::find_if(ListNode::m_nodeList,
      static_cast<ListNode*>(nullptr),
      [p_serviceNumber](const ListNode& s) {
         return id==s.m_id;
      }
);
```

I also tried this using the `begin()` and `end()` functions defined. The only thing that works is the following:

```
for (auto *s = m_nodeList; s != nullptr; s = s->m_nextNode)
{
    if (s->m_id == id)
        return s;
}
return nullptr;
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You are missing everything about building a C++ container and iterators. I'm not sure where I read the rules for it but try Stroustrup's C++ book. Also read the code in the C++ Standard Library.

Comment: Also, there is certainly an existing linked list container already written that you could use.

Comment: Why are you trying to build your own linked list class?

Comment: @n.m. It's almost always academic exercises, to learn about data structures.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8054273/how-to-implement-an-stl-style-iterator-and-avoid-common-pitfalls

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the feedback.

I develop software for safety critical applications. Using dynamic memory is generally not allowed. The STL linked list class is an independent data structure used to maintain a list of objects. We have objects and just need them to function as STL compatible container objects. (that is the why)

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8054273/how-to-implement-an-stl-style-iterator-and-avoid-common-pitfalls/%22iterators%20and%20common%20pitfalls%22) was very useful. The problem was an errant definition of the increment operator.

Comment: There are intrusive linked list implementations in e.g. boost you should probably look into.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `begin`/`end` functions return a pointer, so when `find_if` increments the pointer with `++`, it just increments the pointer to point at garbage after the first node, and does not use your `operator++`.

You need to define an iterator class object, which defines both (unary) `operator*` and `operator++`, and have begin/end return that.  This iterator class likely just contains a single pointer field.

Comment: Forgot to mention the operator++() in the original post. This is what I have now.

 <code>// Container support functions
 typedef AbstractService*  iterator;
 typedef const AbstractService* const_iterator;

 static iterator begin() noexcept  {return iterator(AbstractService::m_serviceList);}
 static iterator end() noexcept  {return iterator(nullptr);}

 iterator& operator++() {return m_nextService;}</code>

Comment: That won't work, as `++` is already defined for pointer types and can't be overloaded -- you can only overload operators on class types, not on "builtin" types.  So you need your iterator type to be a class type, not a pointer type.  Pointers only work as iterators for raw arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Looking into the problem with the debugger, this is what I discovered. Defining ListNode* to be iterator, STL is interpreting this as a random access iterator, not a forward interator. In this case it is expecting begin() and end() to be pointers into an array where they may be subtracted to determine a relationship. Since end() is being defined as nullptr, the find_if() algorithm is not performing the increment operator and aborting immediately, returning end().

So I need to figure out how to define a forward_iterator so the list traversal works properly.