# The question on iterator begin() function

Tags: c++, iterator

Below the link where I see how iterator begin function works but not understand clearly.

https://secweb.cs.odu.edu/~zeil/cs361/web/website/Lectures/iterators/pages/implem.html

In their, I see begin function but don't understand how it works

```
  Book::iterator Book::begin()
  {
   Book::iterator it;
   it->pos = authors;
    return it;
  };
```

in this  `it` is object but in this `it->` what is doing i think this overloaded with 
   `operator->()` I think it work like a  `it.operator->().pos` but I don't know for sure 
after that why it return `it` my question is what is  `return it` does I'm not getting clear picture for this.

Comment: Does this code compile? I can't find the class specification for `Book::iterator`, so I can't tell what the member access operator for `Book::iterator` does. Without the code for `Book::iterator::operator->()`, there's no way to know.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz https://secweb.cs.odu.edu/~zeil/cs361/web/website/Lectures/iterators/pages/ar01s02s03.html

Comment: in this book class declare

Comment: The `->` is the class member reference operator initializing `it->pos` to the first node in `AuthorListNode* authors;` (so your `begin()` iterator returns a pointer with `pos` that points to the first node in the list.)

Comment: @AbhiSarkar Maybe I'm blind, but I still can't see where `Book::iterator::operator->()` is defined.

Comment: **DavidSchwartz**  i think you are right actually im getting confuse.

Answer (score 1):

Your `class Book` contains a `struct AuthorListNode` and a pointer to type `struct AuthorListNode` that is used as a pointer to the beginning node in a linked list:

```
class Book {
  struct AuthorListNode {
     Author data;
     AuthorListNode* next;
  };
  ...
private:
  ...
  AuthorListNode* authors;  // linked list of pointers to authors
  ...
};
```

In the iterator for `Book::iterator Book::begin()`, `it->pos = authors;` sets the `pos` member of the iterator `it` to the beginning of your linked-list returning the pointer `it` with the `pos` member initialized to point to the start of the linked-list allowing you to iterate from the beginning of `authors`.

(note: `AuthorIterator::pointer AuthorIterator::operator->()` has `return &(pos->data);` so as identified by [&AlanBirtles](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5494370/alan-birtles) in his answer using `it->pos` may well be a bug in the documentation)

Comment: **David C.Rankin** can you refer some sites or tutorial from where i can learn iterator full tutorial

Comment: I was actually reading through your class syllabus and it does a pretty good job of describing the iterator integration. I would use your guide and the StackOverflow page [How to implement an STL-style iterator and avoid common pitfalls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8054273/how-to-implement-an-stl-style-iterator-and-avoid-common-pitfalls) to get a simple iterator working and you can apply what you learn to the rest.

Comment: **David C.Rankin** actually this resource i get from the internet from where i learn this.

Comment: @AbhiSarkar the `->` is an error in your implementation. I wrote a short iterator implementation from your documentation and you do need `it.pos` instead of `it->pos`, see [Class Iterator](https://susepaste.org/48128894). It was unclear given multiple typedefs over multiple links you cite, but `Book::iterator it;` really does just declare an instance of `Book::iterator` not a pointer to one making `int.pos` proper.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure this is a bug, it should just be `it.pos = authors` as it is trying to set the value of the iterator not dereference the iterator (which is not initialised so will probably crash) and set a value on the pointed to node.