Using range-based for loops and range adaptors with non-copyable input iterators
While the legacy C++17 named requirement InputIterator requires the iterator to be copyable, the new C++20 concept std::input_iterator does not.
But I tried to use std::views::drop(1) on a custom range that uses non-copyable iterators, and it didn't compile, issuing errors about my InputIterator not being copyable. So it seems that in fact a range does require their iterators to be copyable.
Minimal example:
#include <iterator>
#include <ranges>
#include <iostream>

class InputIterator {
public:
    using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
    using value_type = int; 
    
    // Movable
    InputIterator(InputIterator&&) = default;
    InputIterator& operator=(InputIterator&&) = default;
    
    // Non-copyable
    InputIterator(const InputIterator&) = delete;
    InputIterator& operator=(const InputIterator&) = delete;
    
    int operator*() const { return *p_; } 
    InputIterator& operator++() { ++p_; return *this; }
    void operator++(int) { ++*this; }
    
    // Not required for input_iterator concept, but used for the rest of the example
    InputIterator() = default;
    InputIterator(const int* p) : p_(p) {}
    bool operator==(const InputIterator& other) const = default;
    bool operator!=(const InputIterator& other) const = default;
    
private:  
    const int* p_ = {};
};
 
static_assert(std::input_iterator<InputIterator>);

class InputView : public std::ranges::view_interface<InputView> {
public:
    InputIterator begin() const { return {array}; };   // RVO so OK even if non-copyable
    InputIterator end() const { return {array + 4}; }; // RVO so OK even if non-copyable
    
private:
    int array[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
};

int main() {
    // OK
    InputView view;

    // OK
    for (int x : view) {
        std::cout << x << " ";
    }
    
    // Does not compile
    for (int x : view | std::views::drop(1)) {
        std::cout << x << " ";
    }

    // Does not compile
    static_assert(std::ranges::input_range<InputView>);
}

The compile errors include things like:
[...]
note: because type constraint 'sentinel_for<InputIterator, __range_iter_t<InputView &> >' was not satisfied:
note: because 'InputIterator' does not satisfy 'semiregular'
note: because 'InputIterator' does not satisfy 'copyable'
note: because 'InputIterator' does not satisfy 'copy_constructible'
[...]

Is there a workaround to be able to use range adaptors (such as drop) with non-copyable iterators?
Related questions:

Does anyone know why input_range requires the underlying input_iterator to be copyable, while input_iterator itself does not?
Is it bad practice to write generic algorithms that only support input_range and not input_iterator, since the former is more restricted?
In practice, are there actually input_iterator out there that are not copyable?

There is a related SO post:
In a C++ range-based for loop, can begin() return a reference to a non-copyable iterator?
But it only considers range-based loops without adaptors (we can see in the example above that this is no problem), and doesn't really address why input_range seems to require copyability, which makes adaptors not work with non-copyable input iterators.

One question per question, please!  This is certainly a thoughtful post, but Stack Overflow is not at all designed to handle multiple answers to multiple questions in one "question".

@DrewDormann Would you suggest making 4 separate questions, copy-pasting the whole introduction in each? I feel those are related enough... I have found literally zero other questions on stack overflow about non-copyable iterators. The unifying question could be: "How to deal with non-copyable iterators?"

Wait, I actually found one related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63653477/in-a-c-range-based-for-loop-can-begin-return-a-reference-to-a-non-copyable

This is an incredibly meandering text. We don't really need you to take us on a story of how you got to the question, just ask the question you want to ask. All the commentary about range-based for, for instance, is wholly irrelevant to the actual question about what input_range's requirements are.

I must agree with Barry - I don't think any of your four questions necessarily require all the reading that comes before it.  A simple, small code example might suffice.

@Barry : alright, I thought the context might help, but I removed most of it to have a shorter post with one main question



Does anyone know why input_range requires the underlying input_iterator to be copyable, while input_iterator itself does not?


It doesn't actually. input_range<R> requires that:

Let I be the type of ranges::begin(r). I has to model input_iterator.
Let S be the type of ranges::end(r). S has to model  sentinel_for<I>.

Note that for end(), we're not checking that the type is an iterator at all. We're just checking that it's a sentinel for the iterator type.
In your case (indeed in the common case, which is why they're called common_ranges), your begin() and end() return the same type, and so we are checking both that your InputIterator models input_iterator (which does not require copyable) and sentinel_for<InputIterator> (which, in addition to the appropriate comparisons, also requires semiregular which requires copyable).
So for InputView to actually be a range, you would need to either make your iterator copyable or return a sentinel type from end().


Is it bad practice to write generic algorithms that only support input_range and not input_iterator, since the former is more restricted?


I think this question is just a misunderstanding.


In practice, are there actually input_iterator out there that are not copyable?


Yes. Indeed, that's why iterators are allowed to be move-only. The typical input iterator probably should be move-only - since the whole premise of an input-only range is that you can only represent one position at a time. For instance, the iterators from views::istream or std::generator, etc, are move-only.

Oh, thanks, this is super insightful, it's the sentinel that must be copyable! I was led astray by the compiler errors mentioning that InputIterator wasn't copyable, but the sentinel doesn't have to be InputIterator. I'll make more experiments.

I added an answer of my own but accepted yours since it was clearly the most helpful by understanding the underlying misconceptions. And indeed, I agree that the typical input iterator should probably be move-only, which is in fact why I experimented with them. But then I was confused how we were supposed to write range-based algorithms with them, since they didn't seem to work. This cleared the confusion: they just need a proper sentinel class, which typically make sense for input iterators (istream, etc.).

The answer of Barry above provided the most important insight: for an input_range, the underlying iterator in fact does not need to be copyable. But range.end() must return a sentinel type that is copyable, and that is equality-comparable with the iterator.
So for a "workaround" on how to use range adaptors with non-copyable input iterators, the key is to make sure to provide an appropriate sentinel class.
For example, the following compiles (although for the sake of example, it exposes the internals of the iterator and sentinel class):
#include <iterator>
#include <ranges>
#include <iostream>

class InputIterator {
public:
    using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
    using value_type = int; 

    // Movable
    InputIterator(InputIterator&&) = default;
    InputIterator& operator=(InputIterator&&) = default;
    
    // Non-copyable
    InputIterator(const InputIterator&) = delete;
    InputIterator& operator=(const InputIterator&) = delete;
    
    InputIterator(const int* p) : p_(p) {}
    int operator*() const { return *p_; } 
    InputIterator& operator++() { ++p_; return *this; }
    void operator++(int) { ++*this; }
    
    const int* p_ = {};
};

static_assert(std::input_iterator<InputIterator>);

class InputIteratorSentinel {
public:
    InputIteratorSentinel() = default;
    InputIteratorSentinel(const int* p) : p_(p) {}

    const int* p_ = {};
};

bool operator==(const InputIterator& it, const InputIteratorSentinel& s) {
        return it.p_ == s.p_;
}

class InputView : public std::ranges::view_interface<InputView> {
public:
    InputIterator begin() const { return {array}; };
    InputIteratorSentinel end() const { return {array + 4}; };
    
private:
    int array[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
};

static_assert(std::ranges::input_range<InputView>);

int main() {
    InputView view;
    for (int x : view | std::views::drop(1)) {
        std::cout << x << " ";
    }
}


Not <=>, the sentinel should only be comparable with the iterator (not with itself. it's the sentinel after all).

@Barry : Thanks. Indeed, that's not needed. Updated my answer.
