# Pass dynamic array of objects safely and without forcing copies

Tags: c++

I want to define a function `Foo` that takes as argument a few objects `Widget`, whose number is only known at run time. The simplest signature would be:

```
void Foo(const std::vector<Widget>& widgets);
```

The function can be made more general by turning into a template and using iterators. However, if the `Widget`s are not stored in some contiguous form, any signature based on array-of-values would force the caller to make a copy of each. For example, a copy is necessary if each `Widget` is contained in some other object `Holder`, or if `Foo` needs to be called on just 3 widgets that come from idiosyncratic sources.

Copies can be avoided if the function accepts a vector of pointers:

```
void Foo(const std::vector<const Widget*>& widgets);
```

but this makes the function unsafe. For example in:

```
std::vector<const Widget*> widgets;
for (const auto& holder : holders) {
   widgets.push_back(&holder.get_widget());
}
Foo(widgets);
```

forgetting the ampersand on `const auto&` would lead to segfault.

I can think of a couple of solutions that are both safe and copy-free, involving lambdas or a `Foo` template and custom iterators, but they are quite gross. What would be the best design for this situation?

Comment: Why not simply pass a vector of the indices of the `Widget's` you're interested in, along with the reference to the vector?

Comment: if you can use C++20 [`std::span`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span) would be your go to, if not the microsoft Guidelines support library has their own version you can use.

Comment: use iterators. You can apply the same argument that you use in favour of pointers for iterators. If the widgets are actually not stored in a container, one can still supply iterators that when dereferenced yield a reference to the widgets. This can be done in different ways and passing iterators is the most convenient when the widgets are actually stored in a container

Comment: If individual `Widget`s are to be passed in without putting them into a container first, then another option is to use a variadic template function, where each `Widget` is passed as its own parameter, ie `Foo(widget1, widget2, ...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The function can be made more general by turning into a template and using iterators.

This is often a good design. Or alternatively, accept a generic range.

> However, if the Widgets are not stored in some contiguous form, any signature based on array-of-values would force the caller to make a copy of each.

Which is a good reason to use iterator / generic ranges instead of a hardcoded vector type.

> forgetting the ampersand on const auto& would lead to segfault.

Only if you're lucky. A segfault is not guaranteed. Indeed, the programmer must be careful when indirection is involved. Another problem with vector of iterators is the unnecessary overhead of creating a new vector.

---

Example with ranges:

```
void Foo(const auto& widgets);

auto holder_to_widget = [](const auto& holder) {
    return holder.get_widget();
};
Foo(holders | ranges::transform_view{holder_to_widget});
```

Comment: Thanks, this is so beautiful I want to cry. Unfortunately, I don't have ranges in my environment yet, but I guess I can do something similar by passing Foo two iterators and a projector.

Comment: @AndreaAllais This one supports C++14: https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3 It's the library the C++20 ranges are based on.

Answer (score 0):

Iterators are the way to go:

```cpp
template<typename It>
void Foo(It first, It last)
{
    for (; first != last; ++first)
    {
        // do work with *first
    }
}

// contiguous storage 
std::vector<Widget> widgets;
// populate vector here, then call Foo
Foo(widgets.cbegin(), widgets.cend());

// plain array
auto widgets = std::make_unique<Widget[]>(count);
// assign values to array elements here, then call Foo
Foo(widgets.get(), widgets.get() + count);

// non-contiguous storage
std::list<Widget> widgets;
// populate list here, then call Foo
Foo(widgets.cbegin(), widgets.cend());
```

You can write custom iterator class for your custom storage for `Widget` objects. See [How to implement an STL-style iterator and avoid common pitfalls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8054273/how-to-implement-an-stl-style-iterator-and-avoid-common-pitfalls) and the likes for tips on iterator design. Basically, `Foo` above requires only `operator*`, `operator!=` and `operator++` to be defined. However, other operators might be requred to be defined depending on operations performed by `Foo`.