# STL vector:Iterate elements

Tags: c++11, stl, iterator, stdvector

I want to use c++ 11 "for loop" to iterate elements of a vector but i receive some errors ( begin() and end() functions i think is a problem).Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include<iterator>
using namespace std;
template<typename TElement>
class MyClass {
private:
     vector<TElement> vec;
public:

MyClass& operator+(TElement n) {
     vec.push_back(n);
     return *this;
}
int getS() {
     return vec.size();
}
iterator begin() {//here is some problems
     return vec.begin();
}
iterator end() {
     return vec.end();
}
};

int main() {
    MyClass<int> mm;
    mm = mm + 10; 
    mm = mm + 9;
    double avg = 0.0;
    for (auto g : mm) { //begin() and end() functions error
       avg += mm;
    }
    cout<< avg / mm.getS();
    return 0;
}
```

errors:

C2675 unary '++': 'std::iterator' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator,

illegal indirection,

C2678 binary '!=': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::iterator' ,

C2955 'std::iterator': use of class template requires template argument list,

C2514 'std::iterator': class has no constructors

Comment: [It's not as simple as that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8054273/how-to-implement-an-stl-style-iterator-and-avoid-common-pitfalls).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c++11 foreach syntax and custom iterator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7562356/c11-foreach-syntax-and-custom-iterator)

Comment: You should always include the actual, complete, error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `begin` and `end` functions need to be like this:

```
typename vector<TElement>::iterator begin() {
  return vec.begin();
}

typename vector<TElement>::iterator end() {
  return vec.end();
}
```

That's the actual iterator type that the vector returns. By contrast, `std::iterator` is a completely different and unrelated type.

Comment: You can explain this syntax please? "typename vector<TElement>::iterator "

Comment: @paulc: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords

Answer (score 0):

```
    typedef typename vector<TElement>::iterator Iterator;

    Iterator begin() {//here is some problems
        return vec.begin();
    }

    Iterator end() {
        return vec.end();
    }
```

This will be better.

> A name used in a template declaration or definition and that is
>   dependent on a template-parameter is assumed not to name a type unless
>   the applicable name lookup finds a type name or the name is qualified
>   by the keyword typename.

we need make sure `vector<TElement>::iterator` is a `type`, not a `variable`.